# Delegate method Between objective C class and swift class issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I'm currently jumping into project built by different developer in swift over a year ago. I'm aware swift changed through that time so there are few issues coming to me.

There is beacon library calling delegate method in objective c class called:

```
- (void)beaconManager:(ESTBeaconManager *)manager
      didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons
             inRegion:(ESTBeaconRegion *)region;
```

and method that gets call from delegate in swift class:

```
func beaconManager(manager: ESTBeaconManager, didRangeBeacons: [ESTBeacon], inRegion: ESTBeaconRegion) {
    //code..
}
```

swift method compile with Error:

> Objective-C method `beaconManager:didRangeBeacons:inRegion:` provided by method `beaconManager(_:didRangeBeacons:inRegion:)` conflicts with optional requirement method `beaconManager(_:didRangeBeacons:inRegion:)` in protocol `ESTBeaconManagerDelegate`

Answer (score 0):

Your method parameteres are optional, because in Objective-C you can pass a nil as an argument while you can not do that in Swift if the parameter is not optional. You need something like this.

```
func beaconManager(manager: ESTBeaconManager!, didRangeBeacons: [ESTBeacon]!, inRegion: ESTBeaconRegion!) {
    //code..
}
```